# Customize text in Source column of the Event Viewer (EventLog)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, event-log, event-viewer

Is it possible to write to the Source column in the Event Viewer my wanted source ?

(instead of ".NET Runtime" ?)

And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched in start menu for "run", opened it, in the text field I wrote "regedit" and pressed "OK".

Now,I got into "eventlog" folder, right clicked on the "Application" folder, chose New => Key, then named it like my project name (what will actually be shown in Source column in the Event Viewer).

Then simply write in the code : `logName.Source = "MySource";`

Now it will work in the localhost only. If you want it to wark in the server too - just open "run" again in the server the same as you did in the first time, but now it will not open directly what we need, so you have to track the same folders that contain the "Application" folder (you will find it exsactly at the same location like in the local computer), and add your sourse in the same way.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

You could configure an [EventLogTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener.aspx) trace listener programatically:

```
var tl = new EventLogTraceListener("MyEventLogSource");
Trace.Listeners.Add(tl);
```

or using the app/web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add 
                name="EventLogger" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" 
                initializeData="MyEventLogSource" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

and then when you trace something it will use the configured trace listeners:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("some info");
```

Bear in mind that you need special permissions in order to create custom trace listeners. If the custom source doesn't exist in the EventLog the previous code will try to create it and fail if it doesn't have sufficient permissions. So one possibility is to create the trace listener as administrator when deploying the application especially if this application runs under some low privileges account such as an ASP.NET application.

Comment: I tried it and I get the error:`The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.`

Comment: @ParPar, you need to create the custom source as administrator first. If you are running this locally you can start Visual Studio as administrator the first time in order to create the necessary source. But on the live server you will have to configure the custom source.

Comment: I use this to define the source : `log.Source = ".NET Runtime";`

Comment: @ParPar, you need to be admin. Consult the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49dwckkz(v=vs.80).aspx for creating the custom source programatically and make sure that the account you are running this code has sufficient privileges to create custom sources.